# Do wireless programmable remotes for PC-s exist?

Tags: java, .net, usb, remoteobject

I'm looking for a programmable remote control for a Windows or Linux host machine. By programmable i mean i have ready to use (preferably Java or .NET) API for receiving key press events from the remote control and being able to write my own custom behavior logic.

Does anybody know if something like that exists and where to obtain one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find quite a few remotes supporting [LIRC](http://www.lirc.org/)/[WinLIRC](http://winlirc.sourceforge.net/) at their site or [here](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Category:Remote_Controls).

As for Java API support for LIRC, try [here](http://jlirc.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they exist.  Just put ssh on your smart phone.  You can ssh from your smart phone to the host machine.